# Copiar y pegar filas de una hoja a otra Google Sheet macros

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, macros

mi objetivo es pasar filas de una pestaña llamada Requerimientos a otra llamada Archivo: Requerimientos cuando las celdas de la columna F tomen valor 0 con un macro.

Estoy intentando con el siguiente código, y aún así no logro que funcione. Mi idea también es que luego la fila en el origen se elimine, pero primero comencé por la parte del copiado y no logro obtenerlo. El objetivo es copiar la fila desde la columna A a la F. La funcion getLastRowSpecial funciona bien, y está hecha para que obtenga la ultima fila del rango que quiero analizar evitando el problema de que tome la ultima fila con fórmula arrastrada.

```js
function Depurar_Requerimientos_Franco() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID de la hoja)
  var dest = ss.getSheetByName("Archivo: Requerimientos");
  var orig = ss.getSheetByName("Requerimientos");
 
 
  var dest_colcheck = dest.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  var orig_colcheck = orig.getRange("B:B").getValues();
  
  
  var dest_lrmasuno = getLastRowSpecial(dest_colcheck)+1;
  var orig_lr =getLastRowSpecial(orig_colcheck);
  
  
  var numfil = 0;
  var cont = 0;
  var dest_rango = dest.getRange(dest_lrmasuno,1,dest_lrmasuno + 100,7);
  
   for (var fil = 0; fil<orig_lr; fil++){
    var orig_rango = orig.getRange(fil + 1,1,orig_lr,7);
    var orig_ran_col = orig.getRange(fil + 1,7,orig_lr,7);
    if(orig_ran_col[fil]==0){
      orig_rango.copyTo(dest_rango[cont][0]);
      cont++;
    };
  };
 
 
};

 
function getLastRowSpecial(range){
  var rowNum = 0;
  var blank = false;
  for(var row = 0; row < range.length; row++){
 
    if(range[row][0] === "" && !blank){
      rowNum = row;
      blank = true;
    }else if(range[row][0] !== ""){
      blank = false;
    };
  };
  return rowNum;
};
```

Comment: pudiste solucionarlo?